# Тавтология ли это?

Tags: тавтология, корень-слова

*Дать задание.*

Это тавтология или нормативное выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тавтология – это сочетание родственных слов. Сочетание ‟дать задание” – это определённо тавтология. Но, наверное, вас интересует то, можно ли так писать. На мой взгляд, да, я не считаю тавтологию какой-либо ошибкой в отличие от плеоназма. Из-за того, что тавтологию считают ошибкой, людям приходится переподбирать слова в таких ситуациях, и это порождает какие-то мусорные синонимы в языке, которые возникают только по причине избегания тавтологии.